# why does my like query return all records when called with % sign

Tags: sql, jpa, h2

I am using JPA Repository and custom query to retrieve all object matching name:

```
(r, q, c) -> c.like(r.get("name"), ("%" + obj.getName() + "%"));
```

This returns the correct object from DB but it also returns all records if I type `%` in search query.

I do now that I get that because I end up with query that looks like this `LIKE %%%` but I do have a feeling that this should not happen.

So is this a way to do it or can this cause some problems?

Comment: Are you certain that `obj.getName()` is returning something other than `null` or empty string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I execute this statement only if `obj.getName != null` but I do not check for empty string

Comment: `name LIKE '%%%'` is exactly the same as `name LIKE '%'` - which in turn is essentially the same as `name IS NOT NULL` so it will return everything where name is not set to NULL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is that a bad thing? Is there a way to prevent this and should I?

Comment: Whether or not it's "bad" is up to you to decide, after all it's your application and you define how it should work